# React/Redux why arent thunks firing in the order they are called

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Why is FILTER_STUFF firing before STUFF_LOADED when load() is called before filter() in the component?
for some reason the order i see things firing in is this.props.filter(n); before this.props.load(i); in the component.

**component:**

```
showThings (a, b, i, n) {
  if (a !== b) {
    this.props.load(i);
  }
  this.props.filter(n);
}
```

**actions:**

```
export function filter (n) {
  return {
    type: FILTER_STUFF,
    n: n
  };
};


export function jobsLoaded (jobs) {
  return {
    type: STUFF_LOADED,
    payload: jobs
  };
}

export const load = (i) => async dispatch => {
  let jobs=functionToGetJobs();
  dispatch(jobsLoaded({ items: jobs }));
};
```

**reducer:**

```
export const jobs = (state = defaultJobs, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case STUFF_LOADED:
      let filterLists = getFilterList(action);
      return filterLists;
    case FILTER_STUFF:
      filterLists = filterAllJobs(state, action.n);
      return filterLists;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Because you call `filter` (if that's a mapped dispatch or something) no matter what, immediately after dispatching your load.

Comment: Looks like `load` is async

Comment: I guess that`s because your load function is ```async```. try to call it like ```await this.props.load(i)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because an `async` function returns every time a Promise then the sync function dispatch faster than the `async` one [Async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)